# installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Tags: apt, aptitude, dpkg

I found many complains with same error but for different packages. However, i couldn't understand essence of this error and how to fix it. Pls. help if you have any clue about it.

It appeared first when i tried to install rsyslog.

```
# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up rsyslog (4.6.4-2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K02ossec' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K02drwebd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'drwebd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: script ctasd_initd: service Parallels already provided!
insserv: script ctasd_initd: service Premium already provided!
insserv: script ctasd_initd: service Outgoing already provided!
insserv: script ctasd_initd: service Antispam already provided!
insserv: warning: script 'ctmilter_initd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'ossec' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service munin-node and ctmilter_initd if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service ctmilter_initd at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service munin-node at depth 1
insserv: Stopping ctmilter_initd depends on munin-node and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsyslog
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is that is missing the initial directive for insserv in the

> /etc/init.d/rsyslog

So add these line in /etc/init.d/rsyslog after the /bin/bash directive

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rsyslog
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $time
# Required-Stop:     umountnfs $time
# X-Stop-After:      sendsigs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: enhanced syslogd
# Description:       Rsyslog is an enhanced multi-threaded syslogd.
#                    It is quite compatible to stock sysklogd and can be 
#                    used as a drop-in replacement.
### END INIT INFO
```

and then

```
# dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: exactly that already exists in /etc/init.d/rsyslog script :(

Comment: doesn't change anything...

Comment: I know this thread is long dead, but I don't see how this answer is remotely helpful.  So you're telling the OP to add **COMMENTED** lines to his `rsyslog` -- Not helpful

Answer (score 1):

Environment: **Docker Container**

Linux Distro: **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**

I also had this exact error but for when I was trying to install the **Nagios Cross-Platform Agent (NCPA)** within my Docker Container environment and whilst executing my custom `initialize.sh` bash script. Can anyone help me out on which of the daemon services within the /etc/init.d/, I need to configure? and what configuration I need to configure it to?

Thanks a lot in advance!

My bash script output is as follows:

```
root@a132ae571fae:/var/scripts# apt-get -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef install -y ncpa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ncpa
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 30.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://repo.nagios.com/deb/focal  ncpa 2.4.0-1 [10.7 MB]
Fetched 10.7 MB in 2s (5990 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package ncpa.
(Reading database ... 29237 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ncpa_2.4.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ncpa (2.4.0-1) ...
Setting up ncpa (2.4.0-1) ...

Configuration file '/usr/local/ncpa/etc/ncpa.cfg'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
 ==> Keeping old config file as default.
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package ncpa (--configure):
 installed ncpa package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ncpa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@a132ae571fae:/etc/init.d# ls -lah
total 84K
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jan  6 12:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jan  6 12:22 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.5K Feb 23  2021 apache-htcacheclean
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8.0K Feb 23  2021 apache2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.0K Feb 11  2020 cron
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.1K Sep 30  2019 dbus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.8K Jul 28  2019 hwclock.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  608 Jan  2 15:22 initialize.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6.9K Jan  6 12:07 nagios
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.6K Jan  6 12:22 ncpa_listener
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.5K Jan  6 12:22 ncpa_passive
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.6K Nov 27  2020 ntp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.3K Aug 31  2021 postfix
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  924 Feb 13  2020 procps
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.8K Mar  7  2019 rsyslog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.9K Mar 30  2022 ssh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.1K Jan 21  2020 ufw
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.7K Jan 20  2017 x11-common

root@a132ae571fae:/var/scripts# ls -lah
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jan  6 12:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jan  6 12:09 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  806 Jan  6 12:16 initialize.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  165 Jan  2 14:53 remove-nologin.sh
root@a132ae571fae:/var/scripts# nano initialize.sh
root@a132ae571fae:/var/scripts#
root@a132ae571fae:/var/scripts# cat initialize.sh
#!/bin/bash
INIT_FLAG="initialized.flag"

if [ ! -f "$INIT_FLAG" ]; then
## Ncpa install (repository and key already added in dockerfile)
  apt-get update
  export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
cd /tmp
dpkg -i dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
apt-get -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef install -y ncpa
## Set TimeZone to Europe/Amsterdam and Enable & Run Remove No-Login Service
  timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Amsterdam
#  systemctl start remove-nologin.service
#  systemctl enable remove-nologin.service
#rm -rf /var/run/nologin
  service apache2 start
  service nagios start
  service ncpa_listener start
  service ncpa_passive start
  echo "services are up and running!"
exit 1
else
  touch $INIT_FLAG
  echo "services have failed to load!"
exit 0
fi
```

What I would like to do is to install NCPA using the custom script I had built.

And because I wanted to keep a specific configuration, so that it wouldn't overwrite it during the default ncpa installation, I did not use the standard apt-get or apt install ncpa parameter.

Instead I used:

```
apt-get -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef install -y ncpa
```

Thanks for your help in advance guys!

Kind Regards,

Doga